# React Native - less sign in text

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

When i want to display the "less-than" sign (`<`) in `Text` component it throws this `SyntaxError`:

> Unexpected token (126:39)

My code is:

```
<Text>< 30 seconds</Text>
```

How can i display "less-than" in React Native?

Comment: Short answer: `<Text>{'< 30 seconds'}</Text>`

Comment: Or: <Text>{'<'} 30 seconds</Text>

Comment: right, or <Text>&lt; 30 seconds</Text>

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

`{'<'} 30`

no `<Text>` component necessary.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 <Text>{"<30"}</Text>
```